# How to iterate a list from a object that was read using MongoItemReader (Springbatch)

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

How can I to read a List within an Object using MongoItemReader and then iterate a list child object from the object (parent) i just read.

Ex :

```
<classRoom>
<studentList>
    <student>
    ..
    </student>
    <student>
    ..
    </student>      
</studentList>
```

Were I retrieve classRoom via mongoItemreader.. but i want the reader to iterate by student in studentList before I could call ItemProcessor.

Comment: Why don't you make your mongo query return `student` items instead returning  `studentList` and trying to iterate on child objects in the reader?

Comment: The Mongo Document is stored by main object 'ClassRoom'.  I wouldn't be able to retrieve just the student List when using MongoItemReader. As originally I had problem writing a list of objects using MongoItemWriter.. the original reason why I had to use the ClassRoom object in firstplace.

Comment: that is, there are multiple classRoom records. So wont be able to query just the child record lists without the parent.

Comment: In that case you need a custom reader that "flat maps" students from "classRoom" objects.